# How to use require({cache:{ in dojo layers?

Tags: javascript, dojo, amd, dojo-build

After reading [dojo-build](/questions/tagged/dojo-build) tag I've found out many problems that people have with customizing the builds, so I've thought of creating the build myself instead. But I wasn't able to find a reference for syntax used while constructing Dojo AMD layers, namely:

```javascript
require({cache:{"custom/MyModule":function () {
    define(["dojo/_base/lang"], function (lang) {
```

It looks like cache is a map where the module name is key, and the value is function which body is my module file content.

But I don't fully understand the lower part:

```javascript
}, "*now":function (r) {
    r(["dojo/i18n!*preload*custom/nls/all*[\"en\",\"de\",\"ROOT\"]"]);
}}});
```

This "*now" is also a key, but it seems to have special interprenation. Do I need it in my module? Or it is optional?

```javascript
define("custom/all", [], 1);
```

is the last part. As I suppose, it is obligatory to do this define, even if layer module won't be directly referenced anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some reverse engineering:

`cache` object contains map of modules, that are defined in-place. Module name is the key, the value is the function that calls `define` (so it's the content of module).

`*now` is a special keyword, it's absolutely not required, but once it is present, the function mapped under that key is executed with function that can be used to call additional `require`, for example to load the NLS files.

The block

```javascript
  "*now":function (r) {
     console.log('*now is called with argument: '+r)
  }
```

prints:

> *now* is called with argument: function (a1, a2, a3) {
>                   return contextRequire(a1, a2, a3, module, result);
>               }

Function `contextRequire` is defined in `dojo.js`.

Comment: How do I stop this from happening in the first place? Is there an option in my build profile to not cache?